# Where does $(ProjectConfiguration) get set in an LDRA TBrun TCF file?

Tags: unit-testing, keil, ldra, tbrun

### Long story short

Where is the variable `$(ProjectConfiguration)` set in an LDRA TBrun TCF file?

### Context

I have an LDRA TBrun TCF file I'm trying to run using the command-line runner, `contbrun.exe`.

It's failing because it's referencing the incorrect executable path (.axf file). It's trying to read this:

```
C:\Code\SetName\src\arm\LDRA\SetName.axf
```

When it should instead be reading this:

```
C:\Code\SetName\src\arm\SetName\SetName.axf
```

In other words, take the `.\LDRA\.` out of the path and replace it with `.\SetName\.`.

In the TCF file, I think I deduced that the executable path is coming from one of these very similar lines:

```
SH Executable Name = $(ProjectDir)$(ProjectConfiguration)\$(SetName)$(ExeExtension)
...
Sequencer Executable Name = $(ProjectDir)$(ProjectConfiguration)\$(SetName)$(ExeExtension)
...
Harness Executable Name = $(ProjectDir)$(ProjectConfiguration)\$(SetName)$(ExeExtension)
```

I would like to continue using these parameters rather than hard-coding the correct path. That implies to me I would need to update `$(ProjectConfiguration)`. But I can't figure out where that is set.

There are no hits in the file for where it gets set. And searching around for "LDRA" results of course in a lot of hits but nothing that stands out as the one that sets `$(ProjectConfiguration)`.

Where does `$(ProjectConfiguration)` get set?

Answer (score -1):

The best way of resolving this would be to contact LDRA Support at support@ldra.com - the suspicion is that you have a corrupted TLP.

Support will be able to sort you out (assuming you are not already sorted)

See profile for affiliation!

Comment: This is not an answer.

Comment: It may not be, CivFan... but (assuming you are a licenced user) talking to Support will get you sorted.  Asking here will probably not...